# React App deployment in VM server - 302 status code

Tags: reactjs, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-302

While deploying a react app in VM server, I ran across
"Refused to execute script from 'https://domaninname.com)/web/error' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. "
with status code 302.

Request URL:
https://domainname.com/web/error
What I want is https://domainname.com/app/v1/auth
Method : GET
I used nginx.

Someone please help to fix this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.